# How should comment authentication work? Open discussion? Or Registered Users only?

Tags: php, content-management-system, openid, comments, spam-prevention

I'm building my CMS and am up to the comment authentication part of it. I am wondering what type of commenting I will allow. To give you an insight into my target audience, I will be targeting a range of people specific in their field/topic.

My posts will largely be based on development, with some lolcats pics here and there. I would expect some quality discussion from the online community, much like the greatly received articles of [Glenn Fiedler](http://gafferongames.com/), known for his Game Networking articles, which have an extremely large discussion behind them.

Now I don't expect such a large audience as that, but I still want to have the support for it.

I'm asking this question to the community. What authentication methods should I use to allow for an open discussion, but with protection from spamming, and only allow high quality content?

To give you an example, I'm wondering if to prevent spam, I could allow for login (either from my website specific user system, or OpenID). This would prevent spambots, however manual trolls could still login using their Google account and troll with that. 
I could however allow for open commenting, but using CAPTCHA to prevent spam bots, reducing the need for logging in, but still allowing manual trolls.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always a chance that people will manually troll and there is no protection against that. I would advice to use openID because most developers have it and that is your audience. About the Captcha, just wait and see if you get spammed. If you don't get spammed, don't install captcha. If you do get spammed, just install it.

Comment: Interesting, I will indeed install CAPTCHA as this site had been spammed before (that's why I'm updating the code).
I was wondering if you knew, does it make any difference what human identification system you use (image based)? Iv'e been using reCAPTCHA on the old CMS, and sometimes, I even find it hard to distinguish what letters are what, I notice Slashdot has a rather 'easy' system, do I really need reCAPTCHA, or should I stick to a simpler script

Comment: I agree that sometimes the image of reCAPTCHA is hard to read. I would use an easier captcha like a math question. Tutorial for this can be found here: http://www.php-help.ro/php-tutorials/math-capcha-image-against-spam/ .

Answer (score 1):

Like Bob said you are always going to get spammers I would use registration and login but if you are worried about them having to login all the time just set a cookie for a long period of time like a year or so. But during the registration process make them use a captcha image and then also make them activate their account. Or you could track by ip address and block them that way. There are many different ways to control spam by many ways around it too so its your call. I have a captcha setup that works really well and is not tough to read http://www.php-help.ro